# VBA: Sum the values in the row which are to left of reference

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have a 2-dimensional array. I want to sum the values in the row which are to the left of the current position (including current position).

```
Dim Arr As Variant
ReDim Arr(4,5)
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As integer
NumRows = UBound(V, 1)
NumCols = UBound(V, 2)

For j = 0 to NumCols
    For i = 0 to Num Rows 
        Arr(i,j) = ......
    Next i
Next j
```

Is there an equivalent to SUM(X:Y), where I can reference an element in the array?

I think this, for example, would sum the third row:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
   dSum = .Sum(.Index(Arr, 3, 0))
End With
```

but I need to sum to the left the of position, including the current position.

If my array is 2x4:

```
[1,1,2,3]
[1,1,3,5]
```

it would be:

```
[1,2,4,7]
[1,2,5,10]
```

Comment: I don't understand your final result?

Comment: Apologies. Does the new example array help?

Comment: Thanks, suggested answer below. Though you are not adding just those to the left but the reference element itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think this basically does what you want. I have populated an array from the sheet to make things quicker, and placed the sums into a second array of the same dimensions.

```
Sub x()

Dim v, i As Long, j As Long, v2()

v = Range("A1:D2").Value
ReDim v2(1 To UBound(v, 1), 1 To UBound(v, 2))

For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    For j = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
        v2(i, j) = Application.Sum(Application.Index(v, i, Evaluate("ROW(1:" & j & ")")))
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

[This thread](https://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/758402-vba-working-with-areas-within-2d-arrays.html) might be a useful read.

Comment: Thank you. My problem with copying to the sheet is that I'm creating an array in vba and then want to edit within vba without copying to the sheet -- purely for efficiency purposes.

So say my array is initially created in vba like this: 




    For j = 0 To NumCols
    For i = 0 To NumRows
        V(i, j) = i + j
    Next i
Next j






I would then like to get another array, v2, in vba, with the above conditions without having to reference the sheet

Comment: The code doesn't require any reading from or writing to a sheet. You can populate the starting array in VBA, I'm just being lazy.

Comment: Ahhh ok, got you. Thanks a lot!